# Restrict memory across all containers

Tags: docker

I know you can set a memory restriction per container in docker via `run -m <x>`, but is it possible to set an aggregate restriction across all containers, rather than each container individually?

For example, if I have 5 containers and 2GB of RAM, is it possible to configure docker so that it can allocate in total no more than 1GB, meaning the sum of memory allocated to containers may not pass 1GB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now kubernetes does limiting only on container level via resources: limits parameter. And only for cpu and memory.

You could control how much memory/cpu a pod is using, since you define the pod. So, if you assign specific max usage for each container, the pod will not be able to use more resources then the sum of the individual ones.

This is not ideal, because you may want to let each container use as much memory as needed, but the pod to not get past a certain treshold. They have an issue opened for what you want [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/5671)